# Recommendation for optocoupler for SCR and TRIAC Gate driver

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, scr

[image]I want to use an SCR having gate current "Igt" = 50mA and a TRIAC with Igt = 50mA to 100mA. I am looking for an optocoupler IC to drive the SCR and TRIAC. I saw MOC3021 but it's "LED Triggering current" Ift = 15mA max.

Can anyone recommend an optocoupler that can trigger my SCR?

Also, can I use the same optocoupler for TRIAC if I want to replace my SCR?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

[image]

Comment: Part recommendations are generally off-topic (see [Help Center: Asking](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Maybe you can rephrase your question to make it on-topic.

Comment: You seem to be quoting the spec for the LED side of the optocoupler. You should be looking at the output side. You should always post a link to the datasheet for the device you are using to make it easy for your readers to check. There's an [edit] button below your question ...

Comment: Yes, I added the data sheets now.